# nosetests config file python

Tags: python, nose

I am working on nosetests. I know that we have to use `-s` so that stdout will not be captured during execution. Another way is to create `nose.cfg` file.

Can I know where should I create this file, I tried it in the folder from where I am running `nosetests` in command window, it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: You can create it everywhere. just use next command `nosetests -s --tc-file example_cfg.ini`

Comment: Hi Klaus, I tried the above but got error : "no such option --tc -file".         I am using python 3, with windows 7. Is this command not meant for windows?                                                                                          From help I used "nosetests -c example_cfg.ini" and it worked for me.  Also, should I use this command every time I run nosetests. I used this command once and I got my print statements, but second time I tried nosetests, my stdout were captured

Answer (score 0):

This error means you need nose testconfig library download nose-testconfig from here:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/nose-testconfig

or use easyinstall or pip

this will resolve the issue !

Comment: You should add some more context to your answer.